# How to get from two arrays and return unique values from last array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two array like a = [1,2,3] and b = [2,5] and I want result like result = [5]

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const a = [1,2,3]
const b = [2,5]
const unique = b.filter(e => !a.includes(e))

console.log(unique)
```